# Is Apache Tomcat blocking the client IP address?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have deployed my web application on Tomcat 6.0 in machine having ip address 10.xx.xx.90. Then i am making a http request(from browser) to this app from m/c having ip address (10.xx.xx.56).

I am trying to get the IP address of client(10.xx.xx.56) in servlet filter using the below code.But i am not getting any value for remoteaddress parameter in header info and request.getRemoteAddr() returns the ip address of the machine on which the application is deployed i.e 10.xx.xx.90. There is no loadbalancer or proxy in between.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain    chain) throws IOException,
  ServletException {
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
StringBuffer ipLog = new StringBuffer("FILTER_LOG").append(httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr());
Enumeration<String> e = httpServletRequest.getHeaderNames();
if (e != null) {
  while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
    String header = e.nextElement();
    ipLog.append(header).append(" - ").append(httpServletRequest.getHeader(header));
  }
}
System.out.println(ipLog);
```

Is Tomcat blocking or changing the client IP address here ? If yes, then what configuration i need to change to get the real client IP address ?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: @folkol "Tomcat 6.0", Let's read question carefully!

Comment: Are you running Tomcat behind eg. Apache or are you actually hitting the tomcat on the configured port? What does the access log say - can you see the remote IP there?

Comment: Let me rephrase that then. What exact version of Tomcat 6 did you use? I tried to log the remote IP with Tomcat 6.0.41, on a Mac with Java 1.7.0_60-ea. That worked as expected.

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup : I am hitting tomcat on the configured port. Header info is printed as FILTER_LOG 10.xx.xx.90content-type - text/xml; charset=UTF-8accept - text/*connection - closecache-control - no-cachepragma - no-cachehost
 - 10.xx.xx.90:8085content-length - 1052

Comment: @folkol : i am using apache-tomcat-6.0.20...i am hitting request from browser

Comment: Ok. Are all logged ip addresses from the local machine? If so, are you connecting to the server through a tunnel?

Comment: @folkol: yes i am connecting through tunnel..

Comment: If you are connecting through a tunnel, then it is the server side of that tunnel that is effectively doing the request to your server. THAT is the reason you are getting the local ip.

Answer (score 0):

### You ARE in fact connecting through a proxy

As noted in the comments to this question, the client is connecting through a **tunnel** to the server, which means that the one doing the actual request to the server is the server side of the tunnel.

That is why you are getting your local IP as "remoteAddr"

Let Tomcat listen to the public interface, or to all interfaces, and connect straight to the server IP instead of through your tunnel.

Comment: I cannot access server machine without connecting through tunnel....also i am able to retrieve the client IP using above approach in some other app running on the same environment.

Comment: What kind of application can distinguish between a HTTP request that was once routed through a ssh tunnel, and one that originated from localhost? Even if you DO have a magic program like that, the question was about whether Tomcat somehow blocked or re-wrote the client ip, which I believe that my answer is sorting out.